# Symfony2 on Windows using IIS or Apache or?

Tags: windows, apache, symfony, iis, webserver

Does anybody of you have experience in running Symfony2 on IIS on Windows compared to Apache.

What is your favorite Webserver to run a Symfony2 Application on Windows?

Maybe there is a third alternative that beats both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working almost two weeks with IIS and Symfony I will switch back to Apache.

It is a bit faster than Apache. I am able to hit 300ms pageload using wincache. However, the Windows Permissions drive me crazy.

IIS is no real competitor to Apache for me anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I use IIS for local development and don't have any complaints.  I've had a few issues with Windows permissions, but generally it works absolutely fine.  The company I work for has a couple of Symfony 2 applications that are deployed on Windows in production, primarily because of difficulties in connecting to an SQL Server database via Doctrine on Linux (this may or may not be easier nowadays).  On the whole, IIS works well for us.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How long does it take to load the page? Using WAMP/XAMP or some alternative results in pageloads > 2s on Windows.

Comment: I tried it and right now the performance feels horrible, even though I use opcache and cache. A pageload is more than 2 seconds as well. Actually even a bit longer compared to apache.